# Need to get xilinx or similar from 'xilinx/pcf.sh' in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to parse a var like:
        `a=xilinx/pcf.sh`
I need the word before the '/'.  I got it to:
        `xilinx/`
But I also need to get rid of '/'.
I used $(dir $(a)).  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used $(shell dirname $(PCF_IMPL))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`subst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) for this.

```
a = ${subst /,,${dir xilinx/pcf.sh}}
```